# Is it possible to enter command line git commands in GitAhead?

Tags: git, gitahead

I am looking for an GUI for git on Linux. I tried different ones and GitAhead seems very promising.

But there are not all git commands implemented, at least not yet or I cannot find them. One task I'd like to do fairly often is pushing to a second remote. Changing the upstream is pretty cumbersome (and a little hard to find in GitAhead). It's pretty straight forward on the command line, e.g.

```
git push live master
```

But opening a terminal, going to the directory and then running the command is also not convenient.

Is there a way to launch the (external) terminal in the repository root from within GitAhead? Or is it even possible to enter CLI git commands somewhere in GitAhead?

There is a *Terminal* tab in the *Options*, but I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to enter git command inside of GitAhead. You have to switch to the terminal.

There is an outstanding pull request to open the terminal in the current repository from within GitAhead. That will likely be added soon.

The Terminal tab in settings is only for installing a symlink to launch GitAhead from the terminal.